# Plaintext password protection on crash dump

Tags: c, security, winapi, crash-dumps, winlogon

We need to specify plain text passwords with some APIs like `LogonUser`, `NetUseAdd` and others. We may protect the password by keeping it encrypted in memory, and assign a plaintext password just before calling the function (into `lpszPassword` parameter in case of `LogonUser`, or `USE_INFO_2::ui2_username` in case of `NetUseAdd`).

My question is how to protect the plaintext password from external process, especially when this process might crash and produce a memory dump.

It should be like:

1. Protect-this-memory-area
2. Call secure function requiring plaintext
   password
3. Dismiss-protection-of-memory-area
4. Clean-memory-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to protect the memory dump itself.  This is why some systems have them disabled entirely, some have them written to a special place which is not readable by mere mortals, etc.

Comment: It may not be possible to protect memory dump, especially at the client machine. What special place, how to make it unreadable? I see references on how to "attack", but not how to "protect" it.

Comment: Aren't you concerned that a malicious user can intercept LogonUser() and you will pass your credentials directly to them?  I'm assuming you're talking about running your software on an untrusted client machine?

Comment: That's what I am concerned about. If not the running process, but a dump may be acquired somehow. Just like SSP (Kerberos etc), which work on keys, why not these API take encrypted buffer, instead of plain password?

Comment: What if, even in protected environment, some process of admin-elevated level is launched? That process may intercept - there has to be technique to avoid it (if not entirely).

Comment: I know how Kerberos works, and Windows has NTLM etc., but I have no idea how that applies to your specific situation.  It might be a reasonable idea to start from a higher level, back up a bit, and post a new question (link to it here please), asking how to achieve your higher-level goals of secure authentication.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs John. But my question isn't about authentication and authorization, but only about protecting the plain-text password.

Comment: Ah, the old "I have decided to take a nap with these cobras, please explain how to do it safely!"

Comment: No no no. It's not about unsecure code. How can you protect yourself from password theft, just before the call/after to `LogonUser`?

Comment: I will not discuss this further here, because I think you may be off track; I suggest you ask a new question and link to it from the comments here so people will see it, and you can ask more generally how to protect against password theft.